# hide/show div and above all come back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide/show div but in a specific way. I put a clickable text at the beginning and one at the end.

The buttons work fine but I want this thing:

"when a user clicks on the bottom button, the page scrolls back at the beginning of the current hidden div"

```
<a href="javascript:visibilite('divid21');">
<u>Examples (Click to show/hide)</u></a>

<div id="divid21" style="display:none;">

     long html code about 100 lines    

        <a onclick="    
           document.getElementById('divid21').style.display='none'; "  
           href="#divid21"> Examples  (Click to hide)</a>
</div>
```

the function

```
function visibilite(id) {
      var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
 for(var no=0;no<divs.length;no++){
     if(divs[ no].className=='divs'){ 
        divs[ no].style.display = "none"; 
    }
}
document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";  }
```

Comment: Have you tried the jquery $('#div').height(0) method and then .height(value) to restore it? Only problem is that the height will be fixed after it's restored so may not be good for responsive content

Comment: Do you want a solution purely with css?

Comment: Any solution is good for me purely with css or not.

Comment: the href # is makign it scroll to the top of the div.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> Jquery to toggle between hide and show

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("divex").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

> Div with the same id specified in the jquery code

```
<button> Hide/Show </button>
<div id="divex">Div content </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Alas , it's for a mobile app(android) and I would like to keep the possibility to use it without internet connection and I don't know how jquery is "heavy"(all the meanings possible of the word "heavy") .

Comment: You haven't specified android in your tags.